# Resonance of 4 cylinder engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, vibration

Let’s say I have a 4-Cylinder, in-line engine where all pistons start from the same point,

Could I have more than speed where resonance occurs?

I read on a book that systems have more than one natural frequency, so I think I could?

Comment: How will the rotational starting point make a difference?

Comment: It's a "4-stroke" engine, right? So 2 full revolutions of the crankshaft for each cycle, total cycle 720 degrees? Thus with 4 cyl, offset 180 degrees in starting position? (I'm not a car guy tho) Now those numbers would set excitation frequency... (720/4 => 2x/rev => double the RPM). Anyway, both square pulse and sharp impulse at that pulse frequency, excites broadband and harmonics. And the RPM's vary, so you're looking at a range. Then compare to resonance spectrum of the assembly. Long story short, with harmonics in both excitation and response, almost certainly  more than one RPM resonates

Comment: @SolarMike I think he means all 4 fire at the same time, as opposed to the more standard  1 -- 3 --2 --4  or similar sequences.

Comment: Hi so Carl is correct, so it could start as 0-0-0-0 for example or 0-180-180-0

Comment: Pete, great explanation! I think your numbers are right, I just don’t get the Harmonics bit please?

Comment: Harmonic is a multiple of a vibrational frequency ... exact same concept as the way a a guitar string or a wind instrument reed can produce more than one note... in musical terms, the fundamental, an octave up (2x), an octave and a fifth (3x) etc. So if your machine has a resonance at, say, 500Hz, it might also has one at 1000Hz and 1500Hz too. There are also harmonics in common waveforms like squares and triangles, which have odd harmonics. So the 3rd harmonic of a 333.3Hz square wave (3 x 333.3 = 1000), for instance, might excite a 1000Hz vibrational mode....

Comment: All rotating machinery, not just reciprocals, have resonance.

Answer (score 1):

There can easily be multiple  natural resonances of the engine assembly (not to mention harmonics).   That's independent of how the firing sequence goes.

Then, everytime the pulse rate from the union of all cylinders' firings matches a natural resonance you'll get vibration.

Comment: Hi, yeah I don’t really get what the harmonics is here? Is it like this: as speed increases there are more harmonics with that time?

Comment: @Engineguy  maybe start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic